# "a" or "any" with except

Tags: articles, determiners

Are the following sentences correct?

- I don't have a book except this one.
- I don't have any books except this one.

I think both are correct. Could any native speakers please answer the question.

Comment: I like this version better than either of yours: *I don't have any book except this one*.

Answer (score 1):

The second form "I don't have any books except this one" is the correct one.

The speaker is claiming that they have *no* books, apart from the one indicated.  Therefore it is right to use "any" rather than "a".

Answer (score 1):

Only the second sentence is correct.

The phrase 'a book' means that there is only 1 book. Therefore, the first sentence "I don't have a book except this one" can also be expressed as "I don't have 1 book except this 1 book" which doesn't really make sense.